# Detect if http request is from an EC2 instance in our account

Tags: amazon-web-services

We've got an app that communicates via web services. We need to distinguish between requests that come from outside our system and those that come from another EC2 box within our AWS account.

The ideal solution would be to look at the originating ip address and detect if it's inside or outside the network. In our office all we need to do is look for requests from 192.168.x.x. My guess, though, is that it's not so simple on Amazon.

How can I tell if an http request came from an EC2 instance within my account?

Answer (score 2):

If the EC2 instances are in the same region, you can create a security group that allows traffic to come in on a specific port number (for example, 8888) only from other machines in that security group. Add all your machines to that group. Then you can add another web server instance to listen on that port, and know that requests can come only from your machines.

Answer (score 2):

Anytime you have two or more EC2 instances that need to communicate with each other, best practices are that you provision your instances within a [VPC](http://aws.amazon.com/vpc/).  The effectively segments off a corner of AWS's cloud network for your own, private usage (and is similar to a VLAN).  This would easily solve your problem because the requests would come from whatever private address range you specify.

Answer (score 1):

It is actually, just see if the request is coming from any of the AWS [public IP address ranges](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ann.jspa?annID=1701) reserved by EC2. Basically the same as checking for 192.168.x.x

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

In your app, you can simply restrict access to the IPs of your other instances specifically.

Using the [AWS Unified CLI Tools](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli) and the optional (but recommended) [jq](http://stedolan.github.com/jq/) tool, you can do something like this:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances \
    | jq ".Reservations[].Instances[].NetworkInterfaces[].IpAddress"
```

This will give you a list of all IP addresses for all EC2 instances associated with your AWS account.